# Error bars in histogram

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to include confidence interval as error bars in the histogram. However, I am not getting good results. I have tried the next:

```
set bars front
set style fill solid 0.5
set style histogram errorbars gap 1 lw 1
set style data histograms
set grid ytics
plot "data2.dat" using 2:3:4:xticlabels(1) title columnheader linecolor
rgb "gray30"
```

This is my data:

```
 X                 Y         C Interval(-)  C Interval (+)
0.1              0.1111       0.110950699     0.111166503
0.2              0.2498       0.249474612     0.250095218
0.4              0.6675       0.666310581     0.668667648
0.6              1.4962       1.491809644     1.500612543
0.8              4.0069       3.982266522     4.031590962
```

And this is the result:
[image]

What I am doing wrong? Why the error bars are almost not visible? Is it because of my data of because I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine. Your confidence intervals are so narrow that the error bars become nearly invisible - but they exist.
You can check this yourself by zooming in.